# Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate issuing XML error for Azure Logic App

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, pnp-powershell

Creating a new Azure App which uses SharePoint custom action (Ribbon).

In that process I am using Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate command to apply custom action for my SharePoint site. While applying this command I am getting  **'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'**

Because my azure app has more parameters and uses = in the URL(XML not accepting = ), something like below

https://prod-18.centralus.logic.azure.com/workflows/XXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/Hello?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=YYYYY.

How do I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm by encoding & with & amp;

URL: https://prod-18.centralus.logic.azure.com/workflows/XXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/Hello?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=YYYYY

We need encode like
https://prod-18.centralus.logic.azure.com/workflows/XXXX/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/Hello?api-version=2016-10-01& amp;sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun& amp;sv=1.0& amp;sig=YYYYY

& replacing with & amp; as Stackexchange is decoding back to &